# How to stop image from moving downward when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created a header image of about half a page. When user scroll down the images goes down with scrolling as well. I want the image to go up and hide and does not effect the content beneath it. I have checked many single page websites websites where images are on some place and when scrolling they goes up and down with scrolling and does not effect the other things.

I tried to use `position:fixed` but it didn't work, `position:relative` is also effecting the content beneath it.

Example of what i want : http://www.piedpiper.com/

Kindly tell me how to do this.

Comment: Don't do that!  It will give people motion sickness.  (If you insist on doing it, it seems to me that you have a working example at the link you posted.  Have you looked at their code?)

Answer (score 0):

Set **position:fixed** for parent element of image.